# Input data in nested dictionary python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

my data is as follows,

```
graph = {'1':{'2':[0,5]}, '2':{'4':[16,68]}}
```

Even though code below works on my IDLE

```
d = {1 : {2 : [15,20]}}
d[1][3] = [1,6]
print d[1][3]
```

But when i try to read from screen and fill my dataset from the input, i get error
My loop goes like this

```
graph = {}
Q = {}
N,M,T=map(int,raw_input().split())
for i in range(0,M):
    x,y,t1,t2=map(int,raw_input().split())
    graph[x][y] = [t1,t2]
print graph
```

INPUT from screen is in the format, where 2nd variable in 1st line is the number of lines below i.e no. of times to loop, which is 5 in case below

```
4 5 20 
1 2 15 20 
1 3 1 6 
2 4 25 30 
3 4 2 7 
3 4 30 35
```

Above input should make dataset as

```
graph = {'1':{'2':[15,20], '3':[1,6]}, '2':{'4':[25,30]}, '3':{'4':[2,7], '4':[30,35]}}
```

Can anyone tell what I'm missing in my loop?
Thanks

Comment: You can't index into a non-existent dictionary, e.g. `graph[1]` is a KeyError. You can use a `defaultdict` from `collections`, e.g. `graph = defaultdict(dict)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `graph` is defined as `{}` , it has no key:value pair in it, hence when you try to do -

```
graph[x][y] = [t1,t2]
```

There is no `graph[x]` yet, it would not automatically set `graph[x]` to a dictionary for you, you would need to set it manually.

A simple way to do that would be to use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to set `x` key with a new dictionary, this would set `x` key with dictionary if the key does not exist in `graph` and return it otherwise [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) would return the value for the key. Example -

```
graph = {}
Q = {}
N,M,T=map(int,raw_input().split())
for i in range(0,M):
    x,y,t1,t2=map(int,raw_input().split())
    graph.setdefault(x, {})[y] = [t1,t2]
print graph
```

Demo result for above code -

```
4 5 20
1 2 15 20
1 3 1 6
2 4 25 30
3 4 2 7
3 4 30 35
{1: {2: [15, 20], 3: [1, 6]}, 2: {4: [25, 30]}, 3: {4: [30, 35]}}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, if you noticed my dataset had keys as strings {'1':{'2':[15,20]}}... how do I do that?

Comment: Use `str(x)` and `str(y)` ? Or don't map them to int in the first place?

Comment: on a sidenote, there are duplicates in my input, shall I change from dictionary to list e.g {'1':[4: [0,1], 4: [30, 35]]} ? @anand-s-kumar

Comment: Well, depends on what you want to do with those, but dictionaries cannot have duplicates keys, that is for certain.

Comment: How do I do that in the example you gave?

Comment: BTW, that list is not valid, are you looking for list of tuples? List cannot have `[4:[0,1]..` .

Comment: ya i tried, its not possible,  I'm trying to form a graph with multiple edges from same node to be used on Dijktra's Algo, here's a link https://ideone.com/N9eoRY

Comment: If you want list of tuples instead of your `[4: [0,1]..` list, you can use `[]` inside `.setdefault()` to create a list and then append the tuple instead of what is being done right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92079/discussion-between-ayush-singh-and-anand-s-kumar).